# how to find which file is playable with MediaPlayer in android

Tags: java, android, file, android-mediaplayer

I am using Mediaplayer for playing music file.

and I read files and make list with music file.

While I am testing if the list shows proper files with putting fake file such as sometextfile.mp3 etc., the fake file is shown on the list.

How can I find the real music file??

May I get any hint for that??

```
String where = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " = 1 AND title != ''";

Cursor c = this.context.getContentResolver()
                           .query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
                                        _PROJECTION, 
                                        where, 
                                        _SELECTION_ARGS, 
                                        _SORT_ORDER);
```

this is how I bring the music files

```
MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC = 1
```

and the fake file passes this condition and is shown on the music list I made.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MediaMetadataRetriever if you get the metadata of that file it means it is a media file not a fake file.